# How can I get each reducer and its action types?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

What is the easy/best way to programmatically get each reducer and its defined action types?

Is it possible to get the action types for each reduce of an NGRX store?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here.
The action types are only to provide type safety (and became obsolete with `createAction` and `createReducer` in NgRx 8).
When an action gets dispatched, it will be caught by all of the reducers.